# numpy sum axis 1 in pure python

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, gekko

This may seem like a strange question, but how do you rewrite in pure python next line:

```py
np.sum(three_dim_matrix, axis=1).cumsum(axis=1)
```

`cumsum` is supposed to be applied to a two-dimensional matrix, so the code for cumsum I could already find:

```py
from itertools import accumulate
[list(accumulate(row)) for row in two_dim_matrix]
```

If you're really wondering why I don't use `numpy`, the problem is that optimizers for MINLP (such, GEKKO) don't support defining objective functions in `numpy` features

---

Example:

```py
example = np.array([[[ 70,  110,  130],
                     [-50, -100, -200]],

                    [[300,  140,  120],
                     [300,  140,  120]],

                    [[ 400, 180, -240],
                     [1000, 320,  560]]])

first_step = np.sum(example, axis=1)
# [[  20   10  -70]
#  [ 600  280  240]
#  [1400  500  320]]

second_step = np.cumsum(first_step, axis=1)
# [[  20   30  -40]
#  [ 600  880 1120]
#  [1400 1900 2220]]
```

Comment: What's the actual input? Nested Python lists, or a NumPy array, like your example suggests?

Comment: **Actually it must be a python list**. If you go into details, there is some optimizable variable directly behind the numbers, and numpy is not suitable in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the two steps your example shows, `data` being the input list:

```
first_step = [list(map(sum, zip(*rows))) for rows in data]
second_step = [list(accumulate(row)) for row in first_step]
```

Or both steps combined (should be faster, as it doesn't build intermediate lists):

```
both_steps = [list(accumulate(map(sum, zip(*rows)))) for rows in data]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNbsMgEIX3nGJ2wZUj4Z802fQkCFXEsRUkYxCMVbVRzu4CUeNQmcUIzZvvvQH7jVczNSfrluUiUcIHcM7hyEqAqkq1YaIk8Hf4/hC6@4rFWjMmgvhUOW9YYtpU65z8r@UktFGuTsm3zcmQFtpNHcnDeyAFIYMzGhT2Do0ZPShtjUOQXTfreZTYhwnlPH567G181ag8Ui0t9bMu4UdZ@ubMly@KAgbjIN5BTRA/QRDfd2a65OxqTcPwikVqjRLEOjUhHXa3l/xgct8Vq5T7R4mcDV5Tw28lbi6@tfkz4sXvEbEsvw)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by looping into the structure at just the right level:

```
first_step = [
    [sum(col) for col in zip(*m)]
    for m in example
]

second_step = [list(accumulate(row)) for row in first_step]
```

You can also combine all this in one statement, similarly to Kelly Bundy's answer, by calling accumulate right on the rows of the intermediate matrix without actually building the intermediate matrix:

```
combined = [
    list(accumulate(sum(col) for col in zip(*m)))
    for m in example
]
```

Comment: Yeah, my solution is equivalent to @KellyBundy's, but it's slightly different, using nested comprehensions instead of `map`, so I decided to post it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Getting back to the original problem, it is okay to use most Numpy functions with MINLP solvers such as Gekko. Here is an example that uses a 3D matrix. When defining the objective function, just include each term separately.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()            
three_dim_matrix = m.Array(m.Var,(2,2,3),lb=0,ub=1)
f = np.sum(three_dim_matrix, axis=1).cumsum(axis=1)
g = f.flatten()
[m.Minimize(gi) for gi in g]
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
print(three_dim_matrix)
```

This is the solution with MINLP (Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming) solver `APOPT`.

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :           12
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            6
   Residuals    :            6
 
 Number of state variables:             12
 Number of total equations: -            0
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             12
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
    1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.520000002346933E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
[[[[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
  [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]

 [[[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
  [[0.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]]
```